# adding a label over a node ignores MouseListener which belongs to node in JavaFX

Tags: java, label, javafx-2, mouselistener

hi there i'm working with nodes on a group layout and trying to overlay labels for each node. Moreover, i implement `setOnMouseEntered` method for each node to do some stuff. So, if i put a label over a node and enter in the area of it, everything works fine except if cursor is not in the area of label but in the area of node. Is there a way to solve this issue without adding a `MouseListener` to each label ? Here a few samples which will be more clear for you.

1) First, my cursor is in the area of a node but not in label (which is rectangular and text is "Alaska") and the opacity of node is changed.

[image]

2) Secondly, cursor is in the area of both label and node but opacity didn't change.
[image]

So as you can see, opacity of node doesnt change even when it is in the area of node. I hope i had been clear for my question and i will be appreciate if you can help. thanks anyway

Comment: Try to set mouse transparent to true for label, and say, what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set mouse transparent to true for label - a working solution.